# My bisection functions have a small error

Tags: python, recursion, iteration, bisection

My recursive and iterative bisection functions wont work with long lists of the same number.

```
def bisection_it(mylist, goal):
    start, end = 0, (len(mylist) - 1)
    while start <= end:
        mid = (start + end) // 2
        if goal == mylist[mid]:
            return mid
        if goal < mylist[mid]:
            end = mid - 1
        else:
            start = mid + 1
    return -1


def bisection_rec(mylist, goal, start = 0, end = None):
    if end is None:
        end = len(mylist) - 1
    if start > end:
        return -1

    mid = (start + end) // 2
    if goal == mylist[mid]:
        return mid
    if goal < mylist[mid]:
        return bisection_rec(mylist, goal, start = 0, end = mid-1)
    return bisection_rec(mylist, goal, mid+1, end)
```

with the list [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,] I expect the output to be 0, but the actual output is 4

Comment: Show how you run the function.

Comment: For example when I run:
bisection_it([1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9], 3) I get 2 as output, which is the correct index. However when I run bisection_it([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], 2) I get 4 as output which is the wrong first index of 2, it should be 0.

Same thing for the bisection_rec()

Comment: That should be in the question